# Discord reprint message bot command

Tags: python, discord

I'm working on a bot command that reprints the text of a message when the user replies to it and calls the command.

So far this is the code:

```
@bot.command(name='repeat_message', help='help me to understand bots')    
async def repeat_message(ctx):
key_details=ctx.message.reference
#missing line
await asyncio.gather(ctx.send(line))
```

In the above `key_details` will be the details of the old message, for example:

```
<MessageReference message_id=123 channel_id=123  guild_id=123>
```

Looking through the [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html) I can't find a command that would allow me to get the original message. I would be suprised if one doesn't exist, if it doesn't can you think of a work around?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the contents of a MessageReference with two ways.

First, you can use `.cached_message` to get the `Message` object, where you can get the contents by getting the `.content` property. If you were to do that, it would look like this:

```
key_details=ctx.message.reference
msg_refd = key_details.cached_message
msg_content = msg_refd.content # String that holds what the referenced message said
```

The only problem with using `.cached_message` is that it can only fetch from the bot's message cache, so if it's not in the cache, then it'll return None.

To mitigate, another solution you could use is using `fetch_message()`. This will guarantee a message object, but is slower (though likely by a marginal amount). If you were to use this function, your code would look something like this:

```
key_details=ctx.message.reference
msg_refd = await ctx.fetch_message(key_details.message_id)
msg_content = msg_refd.content # String that holds what the referenced message said
```